# Facebook Tab - Vimeo iframe video stopped working

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, video, vimeo

I made an app in Facebook that has some simple html including an iframe containing a vimeo video. This app has worked fine for the last year or so, but all of the sudden the video doesn't show up. I've double checked the code of the page (made a stand-alone html page of it and it worked fine)

Does anybody know if Facebook has changed their policy on iframes or embedded video? If so any suggestions?

Here is a link to the app (on Facebook): https://www.facebook.com/LastFrontierHeli/app_367384316627957

And here is the code for the app:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome</title>
<style type="text/css">
  <!--
  .container {
    height: 810px;
    width: 841px;
  }
  -->
  </style>
</head>

  <body>
<div class="container">
<img src="http://www.lastfrontierheli.com/images/facebook/facebook_welcome_header.jpg" alt="header" />
<img src="http://www.lastfrontierheli.com/images/facebook/facebook_welcome_vid_left.jpg" alt="vid left" />
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/30746400?byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="658" height="370" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<img src="http://www.lastfrontierheli.com/images/facebook/facebook_welcome_vid_right.jpg" alt="vid right" />
<img src="http://www.lastfrontierheli.com/images/facebook/facebook_welcome_content.jpg" alt="content" /><a href="http://www.lastfrontierheli.com" target="_blank">
<img src="http://www.lastfrontierheli.com/images/facebook/facebook_welcome_button_website.jpg" alt="website button" border="0" /></a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/LastFrontierHeli" target="_parent">
<img src="http://www.lastfrontierheli.com/images/facebook/facebook_welcome_button_facebook.jpg" alt="facebook button" border="0" /></a>
</div>
</body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out what's wrong Iv'e just used Chrome Developer tools,
and under Console you could see this line:

> [blocked] The page at https://367384316627957.iframehost.com/966373?signed_request=incxTmuyY3_vzi…NlciI6eyJjb3VudHJ5IjoiaWwiLCJsb2NhbGUiOiJlbl9VUyIsImFnZSI6eyJtaW4iOjIxfX19 **ran insecure content from** http://player.vimeo.com/video/30746400?byline=0&portrait=0.

So incase you didn't know - facebook requires all data to be encrypted (served via SSL).

just change your iframe from http://player.vimeo.. to http**s**://player.vimeo
and it should work fine.

Comment: Guy your a champ! Thanks so much for the help!